# select count over partition by

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

I am learning window functions in sql server. I am using AdventrueWorks2012 database for practice. I want to calculate total number of sales and purchases for each item in the store.

The classic solution can be like

```
    SELECT ProductID,
       Quantity,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   AdventureWorks.Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
        WHERE  PurchaseOrderDetail.ProductID = p.ProductID) TotalPurchases,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
        WHERE  SalesOrderDetail.ProductID = p.ProductID)    TotalSales
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ProductID,
                        Quantity
        FROM   AdventureWorks.Production.ProductInventory) p
```

Trying to **convert to window functions** gives me wrong results:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT d.ProductID,
                Quantity,
                Count(d.ProductID)
                  OVER(
                    PARTITION BY d.ProductID)  TotalPurchases,
                Count(d2.ProductID)
                  OVER(
                    PARTITION BY d2.ProductID) TotalSales
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ProductID,
                        Quantity
        FROM   AdventureWorks.Production.ProductInventory) p
       INNER JOIN AdventureWorks.Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail d
               ON p.ProductID = d.ProductID
       INNER JOIN AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderDetail d2
               ON p.ProductID = d2.ProductID
ORDER  BY d.ProductID
```

Why this is wrong? How can I correct it?

Comment: By using `JOIN`s rather than subqueries and because `PurchaseOrderDetail` and `SalesOrderDetail` aren't related, you're effectively performing a cartesian join between those two tables. You're not going to get good results by doing this.

Comment: In short, whilst the original query could be improved, I don't think that the improvement to it would make use of window functions; If your main objective is learning them, I'd start with a different query.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

Because when you inner join, result will miss productid which from `ProductInventory` table does not have `PurchaseOrderDetail` or `SalesOrderDetail`.

Comment: Thank you. The output of the second query gives me very large numbers (much larger than actual). Furthermore, it gives me always `TotalSales == TotalPurchases`